# Determine Order of Parameters for OLEDB with Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have some `SELECT` queries containing sub-queries in the `WHERE` clause using parameters.  OLEDB appears to want the parameters in the sub-query to be listed first.  Is there a way of determining what order to list the parameter?

```
SELECT txtUserName
FROM tblUsers AS U
WHERE txtType = ?
AND " +" lngUserID
IN (
    SELECT lngUserID
    FROM tblUserGroups AS UG
    INNER JOIN tblGroups AS G ON UG.lngGroupID = G.lngGroupID
    WHERE G.txtName = ?
)
AND " +" lngUserID
IN (
    SELECT lngUserID
    FROM tblUserGroups AS UG
    INNER JOIN tblGroups AS G ON UG.lngGroupID = G.lngGroupID
    WHERE G.txtName
    IN (
        SELECT txtName
        FROM tblGroups G
        WHERE txtComment = ?
    )
)
```

In order to get this to work I had to add the `txtType` parameter after the other two parameters.